# How to access child class from parent class

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

Will try to explain this is the best way possible. I am currently coding a parser, which accepts Literals, where a Literal could be a Int/Real/String etc...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxjKC.jpg

The link above shows the portion of the code being executed with debugging, followed by the current variables being used. As you can see the 'literal' does not hold anything. Shouldn't it show the value in the Int Literal class? I have also attached the Literal and Int Literal class files.

Comment: What's the "Java" tag about?

Comment: _"Shouldn't it show the value in the Int Literal class?"_ Don't see why. That's not in scope; only a pointer to it is.

Answer (score 0):

`new ASTNodeInt(currToken)` gives you a pointer to a `ASTNodeInt` on the heap, not an 'actual' `ASTNodeInt`. You could get a value from it by doing `literal->intlit` to deference the pointer. Your debugger looks correct, it says `literal` is a `ASTNodeLiteral *`(a pointer) and its value is a memory address.

Also, your code seems to leak memory- you create a new `ASTNodeInt`, and then create another new one and return that without calling `delete` on the original one you created.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ZIc3b

I am unable to use `literal->intlit` to retrieve a value. This is because the pointer points to the ASTLiteral. Is there anyway for it to automatically point to the ASTNodeInt in order to retrieve the value 'intlit'?

Comment: Maybe `(static_cast<ASTNodeInt*>(literal))->intlit`  ? Sorry, I'm very rusty on C++. But as I understand it, you are getting a pointer which is of the parent type(NodeFactor*), but you want to treat it as a pointer to the child type(NodeInt*). So you need to cast.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! Is there maybe a way I can automatically cast down to the child instance? This is because I can't simple tell what to cast the Literal down to, since it could be one of multiple child classes.

Comment: Well, you can probably avoid casting entirely - can't you just do `ASTNodeInt* literal = new ASTNodeInt(currToken)`? If you know you want the child class in the first place(and it seems that you do since your code is in an if statement that checks for this), why not just use it directly? You could still pass `literal` to functions that expect an `ASTNodeLiteral` or `ASTNodeFactor`. Obviously those functions wouldn't be able to access `intlit` though, not without casting.

Comment: Yep I know, I would have liked to access `intlit` though that's why as I might need it for some future code. Anyway I'll see when I get to it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In that case you just have to structure your code so that it makes sense. For example, if a function needs to do something with `intlit`, it makes sense for it to only accept a `ASTNodeInt`- it can't do anything with a `ASTNodeString`. I would suggest that rather than doing an explicit casts, you instead just pass your generic `ASTNodeLiteral` variable(which might actually be an instance of `ASTNodeInt` or `ASTNodeString`) to functions that accept the subclasses- C++ wil implicitly cast for you in function calls like that.